# How to convert included subtitles in not UTF-8 encoding when their encoding is unknown

Tags: video, ffmpeg, subtitle

I'm trying to make automatic conversion of media files (video, audio, subtitles)

I use ffmpeg mainly.

I would subtitles convert to UTF-8 WebVTT files but I'm facing problem how to convert non UTF-8 encodings.

ffmpeg says:

```
[srt @ 0x559e9f111dc0] Invalid UTF-8 in decoded subtitles text; maybe missing -sub_charenc option
Error while decoding stream #0:8: Invalid data found when processing input
```

What to do when I don't know encoding at advance? (Should I use some other program? If so would you suggest some technique?)

Input is any media file - MKV, MP4, ... with bundled subtitle(s)

EDIT1:

full command with error:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:s srt -map 0:s:3 3.srt
```

this pass OK:

```
ffmpeg -sub_charenc CP1250 -i input.mkv -c:s srt -map 0:s:3 3.srt
```

Comment: Also see [ffmpeg: Unable to recode subtitle event](https://superuser.com/a/1433766) and [How to convert from .srt to .ass with FFmpeg without decoding errors](https://superuser.com/a/1540850).

Comment: Are you getting the error when trying to _extract_ a subtitle track from MP4/MKV to an external SRT file? That seems strange. Can you post your full command line?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, WebVTT *must always* be UTF-8 per the [WebVTT specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/webvtt1/). This is part of the reason FFmpeg does not attempt to detect and convert the encoding itself.

You can use one of the tools suggested in [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/301552/how-to-auto-detect-text-file-encoding) for guessing the text file’s encoding and `iconv` to convert the file. (This can be scripted if you want it to happen automatically.) If you have additional questions about this, they are probably better suited for Super User.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but problem is still unsolved. When I input media file with subtitles that are non-UTF-8, FFmpeg doesn't do any detection and conversion. It suppose that I set -sub_charenc manually. When subtitle is bundled with video (most cases) I'm unable to get it's encoding so it always fail. I'm unable to save to .srt also the same reason - FFmpeg asks for subtitle encoding.

Comment: Sorry, looks like I may have misread the question! Whooops, this is embarrassing. See my comment on the question now.